# Error while loading a file in Python-Set Up path Problem

Tags: python

```
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/test-easy-install-20294.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

How do I change the directory? Or how would I make it change so that it accepts changes in the root directory?

Comment: Which command or code led you to this error? Post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to run the command with administrator privileges. It looks like you're using some form of Linux. In Ubuntu or similar, use:

```
sudo easy_install <package>
```

Otherwise, you can use an option:

```
easy_install -d /home/<username>/wherever <package>
```

Then you'll need to make sure that the directory makes it into your PYTHONPATH.